# How can I loop through this array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through this array but it does not return any length. Is it possible?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction()
      {
        var fruits = [];
        fruits["B"] = "Banana";
        fruits["A"] = "Apple";
        fruits["O"] = "Orange";

        delete fruits["A"];

        alert(fruits["A"]); // Alerts "undefined"
        alert(fruits["B"]); // Alerts "Banana"
        alert(fruits.length); // Alerts "0"
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're misusing the Array structure. You should perhaps read through a JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: I know this isn't standard, but it would save me a whole lot of looping if I could get it to work like this, like a "Map" instead of an Array.

Comment: Right. JavaScript has a plain Object type that you can use, but it doesn't include an automatic `.length`.

Comment: Use an object and `for (obj in objects)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays can only have numeric indexes. When you write `fruits["B"] = "Banana";` you're assigning a property to the object (Arrays are objects), not adding an item to the array.

You can either use an array properly with numeric indexes, or use an object with string keys instead:

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push("Banana");
alert(fruits[0]); // "Banana"

var fruits = {};
fruits["B"] = "Banana";
alert(fruits["B"]); // "Banana"
```

If you need the length of the object, use `Object.keys(fruits).length;` [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Ok I see, so my object isnt an array, but, I'd still like to be able to loop through the fruits object in your second example, is there any way I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: @mojarras: If you don't know how to loop the properties of an object, the first thing you need to do is read a basic JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: @mojarras you would use a `for...in` loop to loop over the object properties.

Comment: Thanks jbabey, looks like a `for...in` is the answer to my question. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @mojarras make sure you `var` your key variable, common mistake. `for (var fruit in fruits) { ... }`

Comment: @mojarras I would recommend reading over [jQFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want an object instead of an array so you can access an element by key:

```
var fruits = {
    a : 'apple',
    b : 'banana'
};

fruits.a //apple
fruits['b'] //banana
```

then you can loop through them by key:

```
for( var item in fruits ){
    fruits[ item ];
}
```

One thing to note is that this will loop through all keys in fruits AND any object it inherits from (in my example its only object.prototype).  If you wanted to be careful you could use the hasOwnProperty method to make sure that the property exists on the fruits object and not any of its prototypes:

```
for( var item in fruits ){

    if( fruits.hasOwnProperty( item ) ){
        fruits[ item ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can still access them by key from an Array.

Comment: Yes but in my code, `a` or `b` are dynamic names, I can't just hard code them. Thanks.

Comment: And yes I can, but, I'd like to loop through them, not access them one by one. Thanks.

Comment: `for( var i in fruits ){ fruits[ i ] }`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a JavaScript object. If you declare your fruits variable as an object literal, you can perform the actions that you desire.

```
var fruits = {};
fruits["B"] = "Banana"; // Can also do this as fruits.B = "Banana";
fruits["A"] = "Apple";
etc.
```

Then doing things like `alert(fruits["A"])` will give you an alert message that says "Apple" as you desire. However, JavaScript objects do not have a length property, but you can do `Object.keys(fruits)` which will return an array of the keys of your *fruits* variable, and then you can access the length property of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare array like this.you need to declare array using new keyword

```
var Fruit=new Array("Banana","Apple","Orange");
```

then you can access like this

```
 alert(Fruit[0]);//Banana
    alert(Fruit[1]);//Apple
    alert(Fruit[2]);/Orange
```

Hope this will work